# Is it possible to calculate JTextFields into a JLabel as they are being typed?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtextfield

Is it possible to calculate a group of JTextFields as they are typed in and set the result to a JLabel?

For Example:

```
int iCalc = 0;
JTextField x = new JTextField();
JTextField y = new JTextField();
JTextField z = new JTextField();

JLabel lCalc = new JLabel("Your total is: " + calc);
```

As i am typing, calc gets calculated. I put in x "12" and 12 is shown.
and in y i put "10" 22 is automatically typed in.. ect, ect.

To clarify "automatically" i don't want to use key listener (like pressing tab to for next TextField) (unless it is absolutely necessary) And I don't want to hit a button to do the calculations

Its much like typing Hello World into a String: as I Type the Label will show: "H", "e", "l"
ect, ect.

Hope I clarified enough

Comment: Yes, a computer is completely able to be programmed to do such things.

Comment: For entering integers, use a `JSpinner`.  The `ChangeListener` can invoke the addition.

Comment: When you do this also make sure you don't do it in the `EDT` I can already see a "why does my `GUI` freeze" question coming...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html) for this purpose, add it to the `Document` of each `JTextField` in question and perform the addition operation in the `insertUpdate(...) and removeUpdate(...)` method of the `DocumentListener` interface.

Here is one working example, for further insight :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class DocumentListenerExample {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JPanel compPanel;
    private JTextField firstField;
    private JTextField secondField;
    private JTextField thirdField;
    private JLabel resultLabel;

    private static final String RESULT = "Result : ";
    private int result;

    private void displayGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Document Listener Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        contentPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        compPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));

        JPanel fieldPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3, 5, 5));
        JLabel firstLabel = new JLabel("First Number : ", JLabel.CENTER);
        firstField = new JTextField(10);
        firstField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(
                                    new MyDocumentListener());
        JLabel secondLabel = new JLabel("Second Number : ", JLabel.CENTER);
        secondField = new JTextField(10);
        secondField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(
                                    new MyDocumentListener());
        JLabel thirdLabel = new JLabel("Third Number : ", JLabel.CENTER);
        thirdField = new JTextField(10);
        thirdField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(
                                    new MyDocumentListener());
        fieldPanel.add(firstLabel);
        fieldPanel.add(firstField);
        fieldPanel.add(secondLabel);
        fieldPanel.add(secondField);
        fieldPanel.add(thirdLabel);
        fieldPanel.add(thirdField);

        JPanel footerPanel = new JPanel();
        resultLabel = new JLabel((RESULT + "0"), JLabel.CENTER);
        footerPanel.add(resultLabel);

        compPanel.add(fieldPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        compPanel.add(footerPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        contentPane.add(compPanel);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class MyDocumentListener implements DocumentListener {

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {}

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
            calculateSum();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
            calculateSum();
        }

        private void calculateSum() {
            int first = 0, second = 0, third = 0;
            if (firstField.getDocument().getLength() > 0)
                first = Integer.parseInt(firstField.getText()); 
            if (secondField.getDocument().getLength() > 0)
                second = Integer.parseInt(secondField.getText());
            if (thirdField.getDocument().getLength() > 0)
                third = Integer.parseInt(thirdField.getText());
            result = first + second + third;
            resultLabel.setText(RESULT + result);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new DocumentListenerExample().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}
```

You might have to add a DocumentFilter too to the `Document` to only allow putting `Digit` inside the `JTextField`, instead of any random character. Here is a related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9478124/1057230)

Comment: not only on _insert_ ... ;-)

Comment: @kleopatra : Thankyou for pointing out :-) I missed the part, if the user enters a backspace to cancel the update :(. Now corrected :-)

Comment: you wouldn't duplicate code, would you :-)

Comment: @kleopatra : The best I can think of right now, is that I can make a simple function, and call this function, instead of rewriting it again. I hope you meant exactly this, or else I would be on my way to learn something new today :-)

Comment: exactly what I meant :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to read about listeners in the java tutorial and implement a listner that will convert the strings typed into numbers, and then update the label's text.