# How to make JFrame wait for input before the user can proceed?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I'm making a question and answer game. The user must first pick a category in a JFrame then another Jframe would pop up with the question. What i want is to prevent the user from choosing another category without first answering the question.

Comment: `JDialog/JOptionPane` is the answer, here is one [related example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19056433/1057230)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `JFrame` either use a `JDialog` or `JOptionPane`

See [How to use dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You could make the second frame modal so that no category could be picked if the second frame is not closed first.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the parent frame(Category) before showing the question frame

```
parentFrame.disable();
//Display yours Question Frame
```

Then you can add enable the category frame when user answers the question. use action Listeners for this. Also add a action lintener for close window button. In all these scenarios set visibility of your question frame to false and enable your categories frame.

```
parentFrame.enable();
```