# int field validation in swing for user registration form

Tags: java, swing

Swing work
  I am having difficulties doing a simple validation of a text field that has as a value - an int variable.  I need the following:

- permit only digits
- don't allow a value of 0 or bellow
- It has to be mandatory to fill .

```
private void btnsaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 

{                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:

   User controller=new User(

   new Integer(textuid.getText().trim()),textname.getText(),
   textpassword.getText(),textrepassword.getText());
   controller.saveUser(db.getCon());

   // int a= new Integer(textuid.getText().trim());
   System.out.print(controller.getUid());

   if(Integer.parseInt(textuid.getText()) <=0){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( textuid, "Must enter a value greater than zero"); }
   if(textuid.getText().equals("s")){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( textuid, "Must enter a value greater than zero"); }
//        if(textname.getText().equals(""))
//            {
//           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( textname, "Name not empty"); 
//        }
//           if(textpassword.getText().equals("")){
//           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( textname, "Password not empty"); 
//        }
//           if(textrepassword.getText().equals("")){
//           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( textname, "Password not empty"); 
//        }
    }
```

show error message

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:470)
at java.lang.Integer.<init>(Integer.java:660)
at com.smart.ui.UserForm.btnsaveActionPerformed(UserForm.java:149)
      at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6267)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6032)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

I can't solve this. please help. it's my first post

Comment: Why cna't you use JFormattedTextField with Number format?

Comment: how can use JFormattedTextField

Comment: Try this www.google.by/search?q=jformattedtextfield+numberformat

Comment: @Snahar : Please have a look at, how to [allow introducing only digits in JTextField](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9477354/1057230). You can add further conditions to validate the input. Hope it helps :-)

Comment: I can solve this with default value 0 for int field. thanks