# JTextField Keylistener can't erase input

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, keylistener, joptionpane

I have a JTextField that works perfectly fine when someone enters a number instead of a letter. My only problem is that that the number then does not dissappear. The user can't enter any other numbers but that last number pressed stays always in the filed! Why?

```
    searchF.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
                char ch = e.getKeyChar();
                if(Character.isDigit(ch)){
                    searchF.setText(" ");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter Only Names or Surnames. Letters Only Allowed");
                    searchF.setText(" ");
                   }
               }
 });
```

Comment: You should use a `DocumentFilter` for that!!

Comment: One [related example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9478124/1057230), using `DocumentFilter` :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is another way of coming at the issue, Consume the key event if it is a number, that way the user doesn't lose their input but you still get the message.

```
  if(Character.isDigit(ch)){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter Only Names or Surnames. Letters Only Allowed");
             e.consume();
               }
```

Comment: @Lambros, this is NOT the proper solution. Try pasting some text into the text field and see what happens.

Comment: text works fine! but numbers don't.. that's what I wanted! :)

Comment: @Lambros he meant try pasting (via clipboard) some text (which contains numbers) into it. Since you're catching key-presses and check them for being a digit you can press `ctrl+v` which won't get caught by your checking for a digit. The text you're pasting will then be put into the textfield while it can contain numbers.

Comment: @Lambros by using a `DocumentFilter`; @nIcE cOw commented on your question showing a [related example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477354/how-to-allow-introducing-only-digits-in-jtextfield/9478124#9478124)

Answer (score 4):

> I have a JTextField that works perfectly fine when someone enters a
>   number instead of a letter. My only problem is that that the number
>   then does not dissappear.

- [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) isn't proper `Listener` for `Swing JComponents`, nor for [JTextComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html)
- use [DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) for plain vanilla [JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html)
- use [JFormattedTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) with `Number Formatter`
- [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#features) inside events fired from listener must be wrapped into `invokeLater`

Comment: LOL :-) Who are you ? If you are __mKorbel__, than who is [mKorbel](http://stackoverflow.com/users/714968/mkorbel), though the way you posted this answer, resembles very much like his's :-)

Comment: @nIcE cOw once time I'm <start .... blablabla ..../end> by using  [OpenID](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190442/myopenid-no-longer-supported-add-alternative-login-method-to-your-account)  for login to SO....,  aaaaand today I decided to add more loggin, rest of my always, (and sure) enless success everywhere you can to see .... aaach

Comment: @nIcE cOw but its exciting to be newbee here, I'm going crazy from rulles here, how easy my live (here) was up to today ....

Comment: On the other hand, you aren't (for very a brief time, with your rate of gaining reputation), bothered by the endless close vote queue. The rules won't bother you long.

Comment: @kiheru :-) and there are two possibilities a) I have to built my rep again..., (already asked my success) mods will merge my two accounts ....

Comment: @mKorbel : Thankyou for letting us know, I didn't knew that fact, that they are about to shut down OpenID login thingy. I just created a new login for myself too :-)

Answer (score 3):

You'll get the event before it's handled by the `TextField`.
What you can do is [consume](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#consume%28%29) the event, that way the `TextField` won't receive it.

(A better approach might be a `DocumentFilter`, you can still copy-paste numbers into the `TextField` with the `KeyListener`.)

Comment: +1 for DocumentFilter (right and correct in contrast with accepted answer)