# java - How to set jtextfield can be filled by numbers only and popup a message dialog on jbutton

Tags: java

So, I'm trying to make a simple program. I want to fill the `jtextfield` with anything (symbols,number or words) but when I click on `jubutton` there's a message dialog appears

This is my code,but it's not working as I want,because when I enter a character after a number the message dialog didn't shown up

```
if (!txtphone.getText().contains("1")&&!txtphone.getText().contains("2")&&!txtphone.getText().contains("3")&&!txtphone.getText().contains("4")&&!txtphone.getText().contains("5")&&!txtphone.getText().contains("6")&&!txtphone.getText().contains("7")&&!txtphone.getText().contains("8")&&!txtphone.getText().contains("9")&&!txtphone.getText().contains("0")) 
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Input must number");
    txtphone.setText("");
}
```

Comment: are you sure you want to allow characters in your textfield as long as there are also digits ? because it looks like your textfield should represent telephone numbers... do you really just want to check if there are any numbers or do you want the textfield to only accept numbers ?

Comment: The `contains` method looks for a character appearing anywhere in the string, so if you've typed "1a" then `.contains("1")` will return `true`.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Use a `JFormattedTextField`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex

```
if(!txtphone.getText().matches("\\d+")){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Input must number");
    txtphone.setText("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`DocumentFilter` is a better choice for what you want. You have a lot of examples in SO. Check [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477354/how-to-allow-introducing-only-digits-in-jtextfield).

Answer (score 0):

Currently you check if there are numbers in the `JTextfield`, but you want to know if there are ONLY numbers in it:

```
if (!txtphone.getText().matches("[0-9]+")) 
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Input must number");
    txtphone.setText("");
}
```