# How to prevent a user inputing numeric values

Tags: java, swing, validation, actionlistener, jtextfield

I'm creating a GUI for a club and am trying to set up a test so that when a new user is prompted to input their name, they will not be able to input any numeric values.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
else if((this.jTextFieldName.getText() ){
        errorMessage = "Name is not acceptable";
        this.jTextFieldNameActionPerformed(requestFocusInWindow());
}
```

The space after getText() in the first line is where I need to input a test but I can't find a way to do this that works.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Check out the methods in the String API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: You're looking for regular expressions.

Answer (score 4):

The best way in swing is if you are using `PlainDocument` as document for your textComponent. It's to use a [DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html). Take a look in how to do it in [Text Component Features implementing a DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter). You have to override `ìnsertString` method then there you can use your regex. Here you have an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9478124/2415194) using DocumentFilter.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try with a regex?

`else if(this.jTextFieldName.getText().matches(".*\\d+.*") ){`

Answer (score 0):

If you can then go for it

```
jTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
      char c = e.getKeyChar();
      if (!((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A') && (c <= 'Z') ||
         (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) ||
         (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE))) {
        getToolkit().beep();
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Enter only Alphabets");
        e.consume();
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Actually using a `keyListener` is not the proper way.

Comment: Don't use a `KeyListener` for a text field. The correct way is to use a `DocumentFilter` or even a `JFormattedTextField`

Comment: @peeskillet  Thank you, I will follow you next time.

Answer (score 0):

Try the regex `^[0-9]+$`.

You can implement it like this:

```
this.jTextFieldName.getText().matches("^[0-9]+$")
```

Comment: Acoording to the question, _"they will **not** be able to input any numeric values"_

Comment: Problem is that this matches only completely numerical answers. So "Abc123" doesn't match this pattern. Also would require a 'not ("!") at the beginning.