# Force JTextField to string value while DocumentFilter only allows digits

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, digit, documentfilter

I'm working on a Java application and ran into a problem that I cannot seem to solve on my own.

I've set a `DocumentFilter` on `JTextField` to only allow digit entries, however, the default values are text. I have a button that resets `JTextField`s back to default, and it is not working presumingly because of the `DocumentFilter`.

How can I overcome this problem?

Thanks

Comment: What's the text?  Does it not contain numbers?  What's the purpose of the text?

Comment: It's a character text. As I said it is default values.

Comment: @Yury Lankovskiy could be an interesting question, your requirement to make me sence, but here will based on your SSCCE / MCVE / MCTRE, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value in local variables

Comment: @mKorbel I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: *allow digit entries, however, the default values are text.* How is it possible? Its a contradicting statement. Most probably your document filter is not working as expected.

Comment: Please have a look at [How to implement in Java ( JTextField class ) to allow entering only digits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662651/how-to-implement-in-java-jtextfield-class-to-allow-entering-only-digits).

Comment: @Braj It's not a contradicting statement. When the program loads it has default values, when it's running user is only allowed to input digits. However, there's a button to return back to default settings, which doesn't work because of the filter. I need to somehow overcome this problem.

Comment: The reason I ask is you could use something like `PromptSupport` from SwingLabs SwingX library, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578568/java-swing-listen-an-action-in-a-text-field-of-a-form/20578601#20578601)

Comment: @MadProgrammer That looks like what I'm looking for. I'll give it a try and report back. Thanks!

Comment: @MadProgrammer Works good and easy to deploy. If you post your answer I'll mark it correct. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A field that the user can only enter numeric data into, but also needs to display non-numeric values is contradictive.

Text is supplied to field via the `Document`, there is no distinction over how that content is generated, either by the user or programmatically.

If you're trying to display a "prompt" in the field, you can could take a look at `PromptSupport` in [SwingLabs SwingX Library](https://java.net/downloads/swingx/releases/)

**For Example**

[image: Prompt fields]

When the fields have focus, the "prompt" will be hidden, but you can control this, making it shown until the user types something or highlight when focus is gained.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.prompt.BuddySupport;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.prompt.PromptSupport;

public class PromptSupportTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PromptSupportTest();
    }

    public PromptSupportTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            JTextField firstName = new JTextField(10);
            PromptSupport.setPrompt("First Name", firstName);
            PromptSupport.setFocusBehavior(PromptSupport.FocusBehavior.HIDE_PROMPT, firstName);

            JTextField lastName = new JTextField(10);
            PromptSupport.setPrompt("Last Name", lastName);
            PromptSupport.setFocusBehavior(PromptSupport.FocusBehavior.HIDE_PROMPT, lastName);

            JTextField picture = new JTextField(10);
            PromptSupport.setPrompt("Picture", picture);
            PromptSupport.setFocusBehavior(PromptSupport.FocusBehavior.HIDE_PROMPT, picture);

            JButton browse = new JButton("...");
            browse.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
            browse.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            browse.setFocusPainted(false);
            browse.setFocusable(false);
            browse.setOpaque(false);
            // Add action listener to brose button to show JFileChooser...

            BuddySupport.addRight(browse, picture);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.weightx = 1;

            add(firstName, gbc);
            add(lastName, gbc);
            add(picture, gbc);

            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            add(new JButton("Ok"), gbc);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

I've also added an example of `BuddySupport` which is part of the same API, which allows you to "buddy" another component with a text component.  Here I've done the classic "file browser" combination, but I do "search" style fields like this all the time...

Answer (score 4):

Do one thing:

store the default document some where

```
final JTextField textField = new JTextField();
final Document defaultDocument=textField.getDocument();
```

On button click first set the document back to default to disable the validation on textfield and then set the default text

```
 btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        textField.setDocument(defaultDocument);
        textField.setText("hi");
    }
});
```

Add you document filter back again on focus in the textfield to validate the user inputs.

Please have a look at [How to implement in Java ( JTextField class ) to allow entering only digits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662651/how-to-implement-in-java-jtextfield-class-to-allow-entering-only-digits).

---

-- EDIT --

You can do it by adding `focus listener` on `text field`.

If the value in text field is empty then set the default value back as a hint. There is no need to do it on button click.

Here is code:

```
    final JTextField textField = new JTextField("First Name");

    final Document defaultDocument = textField.getDocument();

    final PlainDocument doc = new PlainDocument();
    doc.setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {
        @Override
        public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int off, String str, AttributeSet attr)
                throws BadLocationException {
            fb.insertString(off, str.replaceAll("\\D++", ""), attr); // remove
                                                                     // non-digits
        }

        @Override
        public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int off, int len, String str,
                AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
            fb.replace(off, len, str.replaceAll("\\D++", ""), attr); // remove
                                                                     // non-digits
        }
    });

    textField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            System.out.println("focus lost");
            if(textField.getText() == null || textField.getText().trim().length()==0){
                textField.setDocument(defaultDocument);
                textField.setText("First Name");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            System.out.println("focus gained");
            textField.setDocument(doc);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes OP can do it at run time. OP needs just two document filters one for default and second for digits.

Comment: thanks, but I'm using PromptSupport instead, it's much easier.

Comment: Go ahead with `PromptSupport`.

Answer (score 2):

> you could use something like PromptSupport

Or maybe the [Text Prompt](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/) class. It is similar to PromptSupport but can be used on a regular JTextField so you don't need the whole SwingX project.