# How to set a default text to JFormattedTextField?

Tags: java, swing

I have the following JFormattedTextField in my GUI program.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
JFormattedTextField DOB = new JFormattedTextField(df);
```

I want to set a default text to the field so that the user will know to input date in the correct format "dd/MM/yyyy"? How do I do that?

Comment: Take a look at the `PromptSupport` available in the SwingLabs, SwingX library, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807407/force-jtextfield-to-string-value-while-documentfilter-only-allows-digits/22827937#22827937)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## You could...

Take a look at the `PromptSupport` available in the [SwingLabs, SwingX library](https://java.net/downloads/swingx/releases/)...

[image: Prompt]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.prompt.PromptSupport;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                JFormattedTextField DOB = new JFormattedTextField(df);
                DOB.setColumns(10);

                PromptSupport.setPrompt("dd/MM/yyyy", DOB);
                PromptSupport.setFocusBehavior(PromptSupport.FocusBehavior.SHOW_PROMPT, DOB);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(DOB);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

## You could...

Use a `JLabel` added next to the field to provide entry hints

[image: Prompt]

## You could...

Use the tooltip text support, `DOB.setToolTipText("In dd/MM/yyyy format");`

[image: tooltip]

Comment: extremely thorough answer, great job. +1

Comment: Yep, that's me, going over the top :P

Comment: I can't thank you enough...The JLabel method will do for my purposes but I hope to use PromptSupport when I am a better programmer...Thank you

Comment: Glad it (all) could help ;)

Answer (score 1):

Delta,

You can input a default value using the [`PromptSupport`](https://code.google.com/p/xswingx/wiki/GettingStarted) functionality of the [`xswingx`](https://code.google.com/p/xswingx/) library.

The quick start guide is sufficient to get you going!

Please let me know if you have any questions.